# Incorrect header check error

Tags: node.js, http, request, gzip, zlib

When I am trying to run the code from below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

var request = require('request');
var zlib = require('zlib');



app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
    makeRequest();
});



function makeRequest(){

    var url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/search?pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=activity&intitle=ios development&site=stackoverflow';
    var headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip'};

    var response = request(url, headers);

    gunzipJSON(response);
}

function gunzipJSON(response){

    var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();
    var json = "";

    gunzip.on('data', function(data){
        json += data.toString();
    });

    gunzip.on('end', function(){
        parseJSON(json);
    });

    response.pipe(gunzip);
}

function parseJSON(json){

    var json = JSON.parse(json);

    if(json.items.length){

        for(var i in json.items){

            console.log(json.items[i].title + '\n' + json.items[i].link);

        }

    }
}
```

I get error saying

> Error: incorrect header check
>       at Zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js:286:17)

I am passing my own gzipped url in the code.

Any help will be really useful.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Always remember to include code in the question itself, rather than just linking to it :).

Comment: what does your process.versions output

Comment: { http_parser: '1.0',    
  node: '0.8.19',    
  v8: '3.11.10.25',  
  ares: '1.7.5-DEV',  
  uv: '0.8',  
  zlib: '1.2.3',  
  openssl: '1.0.0f' }

Answer (score 0):

Old question (and `request` library [is now deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)), but better late than never:

Interestingly, the code in question does work for me on Node.js version 15.13.0, but not on 14.16.0 (keeping the version of `request` the same, which is the latest 2.88.2).

However, just using the following simple code works on 14.16.0 ([live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-dondws?file=index.js)), but not on 15.13.0!:

```
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(body)); 
});
```

This means that for some reason, on 14.16.0 the response body is automatically unzipped (hence the above snippet works), while on 15.13.0 the response body is kept compressed and so an active decompression is needed.