# node.js zlib returning 'Check Headers' error when gunzipping stream

Tags: node.js, zlib

So I am working on the nodeschool.io stream-adventure tutorial track and I'm having trouble with the last problem. The instructions say:

```
An encrypted, gzipped tar file will be piped in on process.stdin. To beat this
challenge, for each file in the tar input, print a hex-encoded md5 hash of the
file contents followed by a single space followed by the filename, then a
newline.

You will receive the cipher name as process.argv[2] and the cipher passphrase as
process.argv[3]. You can pass these arguments directly through to
`crypto.createDecipher()`.

The built-in zlib library you get when you `require('zlib')` has a
`zlib.createGunzip()` that returns a stream for gunzipping.

The `tar` module from npm has a `tar.Parse()` function that emits `'entry'`
events for each file in the tar input. Each `entry` object is a readable stream
of the file contents from the archive and:

`entry.type` is the kind of file ('File', 'Directory', etc)
`entry.path` is the file path

Using the tar module looks like:

    var tar = require('tar');
    var parser = tar.Parse();
    parser.on('entry', function (e) {
        console.dir(e);
    });
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.createReadStream('file.tar').pipe(parser);

Use `crypto.createHash('md5', { encoding: 'hex' })` to generate a stream that
outputs a hex md5 hash for the content written to it.
```

This is my attempt so far to work on it:

```
var tar = require('tar');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var zlib = require('zlib');
var map = require('through2-map');

var cipherAlg = process.argv[2];
var passphrase = process.argv[3];

var cryptoStream = crypto.createDecipher(cipherAlg, passphrase);
var parser = tar.Parse(); //emits 'entry' events per file in tar input
var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();

parser.on('entry', function(e) {
    e.pipe(cryptoStream).pipe(map(function(chunk) {
        console.log(chunk.toString());
    }));
});

process.stdin
    .pipe(gunzip)
    .pipe(parser);
```

I know it's not complete yet, but my issue is that when I try to run this, the input never gets piped to the tar file parsing part. It seems to hang up on the piping to `gunzip`. This is my exact error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: incorrect header check
    at Zlib._binding.onerror (zlib.js:295:17)
```

I'm totally stumped because the node documentation for Zlib has no mention of headers except for when it has examples with the http/request modules. There are a number of other questions regarding this error with node, but most use buffers rather than streams, so I couldn't find a relevant answer to my problem. All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Check here for probable solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438884/incorrect-header-check-when-using-zlib-in-node-js
Issue would appear to be with parser.on('entry', function(e)...

Comment: I had checked it out prior to asking this question, it wasn't of much help. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out, I was supposed to decrypt the stream before unzipping it.

So instead of:

```
process.stdin
    .pipe(gunzip)
    .pipe(parser);
```

it should be:

```
process.stdin
    .pipe(cryptoStream)
    .pipe(gunzip)
    .pipe(parser);
```