# Incorect header check error from Zlib.gunzip() in Node.JS app using the HTTPS module

Tags: node.js, https, gzip, zlib

I have a Node.JS app and I am using the *https* module to make GET requests to a web server.  The headers in the response coming back have the *content-type* set to *gzip*.  I have directly inspected the data and it does appear to be compressed data and definitely not plain text.

I accumulate the chunks as they come in.  I then try decompressing the accumulated data using zlib.  So far everything I tried results in an "Incorrect header check" error when execute the decompression call.  The code below shows the use of a *Buffer* object with type set to *binary*.  I previously tried passing the accumulated data directly to the decompression call but that failed too.

Why doesn't this work?

```
// Make the request to the designated external server.
const httpsRequest = https.request(postOptions,
    function(extRequest)
    {
        console.log('(httpsRequest) In request handler.');
        
        // Process the response from the external server.
        let dataBody = "";
        
        // The data may come to us in pieces.  The 'on' event handler will accumulate them for us.
        let iNumSlices = 0;
        extRequest.on('data', function(dataSlice) {
            iNumSlices++;
            console.log('(httpsRequest:on) Received slice # ' + iNumSlices +'.');
            dataBody += dataSlice;
        });
        
        //  When we have received all the data from the external server, finish the request.
        extRequest.on('end', function() {
            // SUCCESS: Return the result to AWS.
            console.log('(httpsRequest:end) Success.  Data body length: ' + dataBody.length +'.');
            console.log('(httpsRequest:end) Content: ');
            
            let buffer = Buffer.from(dataBody, "binary");
            
            // Check for GZip compressed data.
            if (extRequest.headers['content-encoding'] == 'gzip') {
                // Decompress the data.
            
                zlib.gunzip(buffer, (err, buffer) => {
                    if (err) {
                        // Reject the promise with the error.
                        reject(err);
                        return;
                    } else {
                        console.log(errPrefix + buffer.toString('utf8'));
                    }
                });
            } else {
                console.log(errPrefix + dataBody);
                let parsedDataBodyObj = JSON.parse(dataBody);
                resolve(parsedDataBodyObj);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

- You may have it in you actual code - but the code snippet doesn't include a call to `end()`, which is [mandatory](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).
- It may be related to the way you accumulate the chunks with `dataBody += dataSlice`.

  Since the data is compressed, this (probably) means that the type of a chunk is already a `Buffer`, and using `+=` to concatenate it into a string seems to mess it up, even though you later call `Buffer.from`.

  Try replacing it with making `dataBody` an empty array, then `push` chunks into it, then finally call `Buffer.concat(dataBody)`.
- Another options is that `https.request` already decompresses the data under the hood, so that once you accumulate the chunks into a buffer (as detailed in the previous section), all you're left with is to call `buffer.toString()`. I myself experienced it in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69254838/3002584) and it seems to be related to Node.js version.

I'll end up this answer with a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-6plmvr?file=index.js) of a **similar working code** which may come handy for you (it queries StackExchange API, gets a gzip compressed chunks, and then decompress it):

- It includes a code that works on 14.16.0 (current StackBlitz version) - which, as I described, already decompresses the data under the hood - but not on Node.js 15.13.0,
- It includes a commented-out code that works for Node.js 15.13.0 the latter but not for 14.16.0.